# How to get the MethodInfo of action by controller and action names in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get the MethodInfo of action in my Taghelper(asp.net core2.0). The controller, action,(or maybe area) names are the only things that I have. Instead of getting all actions at startup. Is there any way to dynamically get the MethodInfo of action(like using reflection) at runtime?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  An action would be a method within your controller.  While a tag helper enable server-side code to create and render an element with a Razor file.

Comment: I am trying to extend the HTML “a” tag. In the taghelper, I can get the asp-controller and asp-item attributes. And I have added a CustomAttribute on my action. Now I think I should get this CustomAttribute by  getting the MethodInfo first, by the given controller and action name.

Comment: What benefit will your hyperlink have by indicating method info on it?  Or are you trying to use the custom attributes associated to the method, outlined on the link?

Comment: I have to add “target” on the element. The value of the target is related to the CustomAttribute which I give to the action.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a collection of attributes, in the following manner:

```
publicstring GetHyperlinkAttributes<TEntity>(string name)
{
     PropertyInfo property = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(name);
     object[] attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(false);

     var collection = new List<string>();
     foreach(Attribute attribute in attributes)
     {
          var hyperlink = attribute as HyperlinkAttribute;
          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hyperlink?.Target)
               return hyperlink.Target;
     }

     return String.Empty;
}
```

So for the above, if you created an attribute, it would look for the property `Target` on the object you've passed to the method, for a given property via the name parameter.  You could loop through an entire object via `typeof(TEntity).GetProperties()` should you desire to expand.

I added some logic, to make you aware, `GetCustomAttributes` will return all attributes on your property.  So the line with the cast, would be for if a developer adds a non `HyperLinkAttribute` attribute to the field.  This could be cleaned up, but figured I'd alert you to the pitfall.

So if the following exist:

```
[Target("https://microsoft.com")]
public string Example { get; set; }
```

The above method would return `https://microsoft.com`.

Now, the tricky part-  Your tag helper.

```
public class TargetTagHelper : TagHelper
{
     public string DestinationName { get; set; }

     public override Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
     {
          output.TagName = "a";

          var  url = GetHyperLinkAttributes<Navigation>(DestinationName);
          output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", url);
          output.Content.SetContent(url);
     }
}
```

So the above accomplishes your goal, but has some drawbacks:

- In this example, I create an object called navigation.
- Looking for a property, the right value would need to be in markup.
- Difficult troubleshooting and easily broken, if attribute or object aren't mapped correctly.

But if those limitations are fine, it should allow:

```
<target destination-name="Microsoft">Microsoft</target>
```

Some errors may exists, I wrote this quickly.  But this should be a solid starting point.